# DNN Custom Authentication provider installation error

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

i developed a custom login module for my dnn site, i could install custom login in my local host installed dnn version 05.06.01 (238), but when i tried to install it in my Live site installed same dnn version, it failed to install and shows the Error as follows

Package Installation Report

See below for the results of the package installation

```
Error loading files from temporary folder - see below

StartJob    Starting Installation

Info    Starting Installation - DNN_CustomLoginAuthentication

Info    Starting Installation - AuthenticationSystem

Info    Authentication registered successfully - CustomLogin

Info    Component installed successfully - AuthenticationSystem

Info    Starting Installation - Assembly

Info    Assembly registered - bin\Providers\DotNetNuke.Authentication.CustomLogin.dll

Info    Created - bin\Providers\DotNetNuke.Authentication.CustomLogin.dll

Info    Component installed successfully - Assembly

Info    Starting Installation - File

Info    Folder Created - 

C:\inetpub\vhosts\CITYBROKERS.GR\httpdocs\DesktopModules\AuthenticationServices\CustomLogin\App_LocalResources

Info    Created - App_LocalResources\Login.ascx.resx

Info    Created - App_LocalResources\Settings.ascx.resx

Info    Created - Login.ascx

Info    Created - Settings.ascx

Info    Created - license.txt

Info    Created - CustomLogin_05.00.01_ReleaseNotes.txt

Info    Created - trusterror.htm

Info    Created - install.css

Info    Created - logo.gif

Info    Component installed successfully - File

Info    Starting Installation - ResourceFile

Info    Component installed successfully - ResourceFile

Info    Starting Installation - Cleanup

Info    Component installed successfully - Cleanup

Info    Starting Installation - Config


Info    Creating backup of previous version - web.config

Failure     ExceptionSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge.UpdateNode(XmlNode rootNode, XmlNode actionNode) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge.ProcessNode(XmlNode node) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge.ProcessNodes(XmlNodeList nodes, Boolean saveConfig) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge.UpdateConfig(XmlDocument target) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.ConfigInstaller.Install()
Failure     Installation Failed - Config


Info    Rolling back component install - AuthenticationSystem

Info    Authentication unregistered successfully - CustomLogin

Info    Component rolled back successfully - AuthenticationSystem

Info    Rolling back component install - Assembly

Info    Assembly unregistered - bin\Providers\DotNetNuke.Authentication.CustomLogin.dll

Info    Component rolled back successfully - Assembly

Info    Rolling back component install - File

Info    Component rolled back successfully - File

Info    Rolling back component install - ResourceFile

Info    Component rolled back successfully - ResourceFile

Info    Rolling back component install - Cleanup

Info    Component rolled back successfully - Cleanup

Info    Installation Failed - DNN_CustomLoginAuthentication

Info    Deleted temporary install folder

EndJob  Installation Failed

Info    Component rolled back successfully - AuthenticationSystem
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It failed update the web.config.  Check the `config` section in the provider's manifest, and see if it's referencing nodes that don't exist.  Install the Symbols package onto your live site to get a line number for the exception that occurs (or, even better, get a local copy of your live site and walk through the installation in the debugger).

Comment: Thanks for reply,   It is solved, after i remove the <location> .... </location> tag in config file.

Answer (score 0):

Check your permissions on the installs folder make sure NETWORK SERVICE/S (cant remember if it has an s) has read/write permissions

Comment: Install folder has write permission, because other packages had installed successfully, and i will post all of the statemets in installation of my custom authenication login.

Comment: Check the permissions on the web.config file. Make sure it isnt set to read only and the NETWORK SERVICE account can write/modify it.